# Derivative of functions of the form $f(x)^{g(x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

I am trying to find the derivative of the function $h(x)=f(x)^{g(x)}$. I just wanted to be sure my derivation was correct:

We proceed by using logarithmic differentiation.

$h(x)=f(x)^{g(x)}$

$\log (h(x))=g(x) \log (f(x))$

$\frac{h'(x)}{h(x)}=g'(x) \log (f(x))+\frac{g(x)f'(x)}{f(x)}$

Thus, $h'(x)=h(x)\left(g'(x) \log (f(x))+\frac{g(x)f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)$

Does this look correct?

Comment: Looks all right.

Comment: Looks good just recall in your last step you can re write $h(x)$ as $f(x)^{g(x)}$ because of step 1! Also note that this implicit differentiation technique can be used when $f(x) = g(x)$ such as $h(x)$ = $x^{x}$.

Comment: So that would be: $h'(x)=f(x)^{g(x)}\left(g'(x) \log (f(x))+\frac{g(x)f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)?$

Comment: Correct, that's right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your next-to-last equation you have the prime mark on $f(x)$ in the wrong place. You corrected that in the last equation.

Your last equation is not expressed explicitly in terms of $f$ and $g$. You should replace the $h(x)$ on the right and simplify.

Your analysis assumes that $f(x)>0$ in the interval you are investigating. That is not stated in the beginning, so you should also have an analysis for the possibility $f(x)=0$.

Except for my first comment, those are weaknesses, not actual errors, so correct that next-to-last line and your work may be acceptable. That depends on your context.

Comment: Why does $f(x)$ have to be greater than $0$?

Comment: @zz20s: Your second and later equations contain $\log(f(x))$, which is undefined if $f(x)\le 0$.

Comment: That makes sense. What further analysis is needed for the case that $f(x)=0$?

Comment: @zz20s: Whenever $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)>0$ you get $h(x)=0$, so in any open interval where those conditions hold you get $h'(x)=0$. The expression for $h(x)$ is basically undefined where $f(x)<0$ (though that can be argued against) and where $f(x)=0,\ g(x)\le 0$.